# Android "Shutting down VM" with no stacktrace

Tags: android, debugging, adb, logcat

I have recently faced this issue a lot and I am not able to find any solution to it.

I am constantly getting `Shutting down VM` and logcat doesn't show any trace of this issue.

```
06-08 20:34:25.288  20416-20416/my.package.dev D/app_BaseRecyclerView﹕ onCreateViewHolder begins
06-08 20:34:25.324  20416-20416/my.package.dev D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
06-08 20:34:30.969  20416-20425/my.package.dev I/art﹕ Thread[5,tid=20425,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xb4a33800,peer=0x12c000a0,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
06-08 20:34:30.969  20416-20425/my.package.dev I/art﹕ [ 06-08 20:34:31.169   617:  639 I/Process  ]
    Sending signal. PID: 617 SIG: 3
```

Do you know how to make the stacktrace visible?

Comment: In lieu of having a stack track why not simply throw some Log/Print statements around your various statements?  "onCreateViewHolder" seems like a good place to start your investigation ...

Comment: I did, and eventually could find out the issue. But it wasn't like this before it used to give a good stacktrace earlier

Comment: I've ran into a situation like that myself doing some iOS development.  Generically speaking the error/exceptions are killing off the thread that captures/reports the stack trace ... if I were to guess.

Comment: Crashlytics is able to record the stack trace. I have tried to remove Crashlytics, but that did not help..

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Google Analytics, try to disable ExceptionReporting if it is set to true

Comment: unbelievable that errors aren't surfaced even as simple log statements when this is set to true